# How to create a dynamic definition for AWS state machine on Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-step-functions, terraform-loop

I'm trying to create a definition for AWS state machine generating it from this list of object:

```
state_object_list = [
  {
      name = "task1",
      type = "Task",
      resource = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:test",
      end = false
  },
  {
      name = "task2",
      type = "Task",
      resource = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:test2",
      end = true
  }
]
```

I would like to have something similar to this, so with the possibility to define dinamically the key and the values of each state.

```
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "this" {
  name     = "my-state"
  role_arn = "my-role"

    definition = jsonencode({
    Comment = var.definition_comment
    StartAt = var.definition_startat

    States = {
      for state in var.state_object_list: {
        state.name = {
            Type = state.type
            Resource = state.resource
            End = state.end
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Is it possible? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, use a dynamic block https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Comment: Could you please give an example? I tried before to use it and I'm still trying to use it, but it always give me errors. p.s. I already used dynamic block for other resources, but here it doesn't works for me. Thank you

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: If I put it in the "States" row:
dynamic "states" {
Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain why you want this? The state machine definition follows JSON format so putting your JSON object into the `definition=jsonencode({...})` with minor adjustments to follow the Amazon States Language syntax should work and doesn't create more complexity in the code. Maybe I missed your point.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to accomplish this issue to create a local variable then use it in your resource.

*variables.tf*

---

```
variable "state_object_list" {
  default = [
    {
      name     = "task1",
      type     = "Task",
      resource = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:test",
      end      = false
    },
    {
      name     = "task2",
      type     = "Task",
      resource = "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:1234567890:function:test2",
      end      = true
    }
  ]
}

variable "definition_comment" {
    type = string
    default = "definition comment"
}

variable "definition_startat" {
    type = string
    default = "definition state"
}
```

*main.tf*

---

```
locals {
  states = {
    for state in var.state_object_list: state.name => {
      Type = state.type
      Resource = state.resource
      End = state.end
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "this" {
  name     = "my-state"
  role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::123456789098:role/my-role"

    definition = jsonencode({
      Comment = var.definition_comment
      StartAt = var.definition_startat
      States = local.states
   })
}
```